# Why reading file metadata was inefficient prior to Java 7 release?

Tags: java, java-io

I've read [in Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/legacy.html) that prior to Java 7 release

> Accessing file metadata was inefficient

But

1) why was it inefficient?

and

2) what have they done to make it efficient?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileAttr.html should give an  insight.

Comment: Java 7 offered very little support for file meta data and you might have had to run an external program in some cases.